# How can I add an "on" even to an element inside another element that's added dynamically?

Tags: jquery

I have a DOM element #article and I am loading a login form to this using the 
following code:

```
$('#loginLink')
.click(function () {
   var $link = $(this);
   var href = $link.attr('data-href');
   $('#article').load(href);
}
return false;
});
```

The login form looks like:

```
<article id="article">
<section class="form" id="loginForm">
<form action="/User/Account/Login" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
.....
```

How can I attach some action to the form submit? At the moment I have this
code:

```
$("loginForm").on("submit", function () {
   var $form = $(this);
```

I know this won't work as loginForm is added later on. What I need is a way
to attach to #article when the loginForm submit is clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) has a callback that it fires once the content is loaded, so:

```
$('#article').load(href, function() {
    // Hook up the new elements here
});
```

> What I need is a way to attach to #article when the loginForm submit is clicked.

So in the `load` callback you'd hook `submit` on the form and in the event handler you'd do whatever it is you want to do to `#article`, e.g.:

```
$('#article').load(href, function() {
    $("#loginForm").on("submit", function() {
        // Code here to do further things with #article
    });
});
```

(Of course, unless the form has a `target` that opens a new window, or you cancel the standard form submission and send the data another way, the page would get completely torn down by the form submission and replaced by the resulting page from the server, so the changes you make to `#article` won't last long. But I'm guessing you're preventing that, or that the changes you're making are meant to be only until the page gets torn down by the form submission.)

---

Side note: It was probably just a typo in the question, but you had `$("loginForm")` rather than `$("#loginForm")`.